# ADT - any way to preview Views inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have quite a large Layout which is placed inside a `ScrollView.` In the graphical Editor, I don't have the possibility to preview elements for which you'd normally have to scroll, since they're just "cut off" from the screen. This really pisses me of. Is there any ADT settings I don't know about?

Answer (score 1):

Try to show it in a Tablet 10.1 preview